# Text display on GUI

Tags: qt, text, display, scrollable

In my Qt GUI application, there are 2 threads.

The non-GUI thread receives data on a serial port very frequently. This data needs to be displayed on the GUI which is the main thread. Scrolling also needs to be implemented.

How do I implement this? What Qt classes should be used?

Comment: You need to add more information about your code, why exactly are using a separate thread for your serial port? As a general rule, updating the GUI should be done from the main thread only, you may want to switch to a single threaded design or use cross-thread signals to update the GUI. You may want to take a look at the [Qt Terminal Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-terminal-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a signal from the thread, containing the QString variable, and create a slot in the Widget containing the label to receive that data.

Documentation : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/signalsandslots.html

Here you have a basic prototype for your needs :

In your customthread.h

```
signals:
    portRead(QString text);
```

In your customthread.cpp

```
void process() //Your process function
{
    QString text = readFromSerialPort(); // Your function that reads the SP

    emit portRead(text)
}
```

In your mainwindow.h

```
slots:
    void setLabelText(QString text);
```

In your mainwindow.cpp

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
{
    CustomThread *thread = new CustomThread();
    //Some code

    connect(thread,SIGNAL(portRead(QString)),this,SLOT(setLabelText(QString)));
}

void setLabelText(QString text)
{
    this->label->setText(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Florent Uguet. Since the serial data will be received frequently, all the data from there needs to be displayed on the main window and this will require "scrolling" also. How can I implement scrolling?

Comment: @Aham That's another question, you will have to ask it separately. But take a look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qscrollarea.html